# Panorama picture as a child view in Android

Tags: android, view, android-activity, panoramas

I am using Panoramagl library for android to display some panoramic pictures. The example project is working great. The Problem is that now I want to display panoramic picture as a child view and I can't add it as a child. It throws an android.view.InflateException when I try to add it as a child from xml.
It also gives me a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException : PLView(Context,AttributeSet).

After further looking into the library I found out that the PLView extends a class PLViewBase that eventually extends Activity.

So basic problem is how do I add an Activity as a View in an Activity class??

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was doing it all wrong I wanted to add a layout to panoramagl library and was trying to child the library view instead I did it by making ,the view i wanted,  child to panoramagl view by using "addContentView"